# Bongard n°2: Shoelace

Tags: pattern, bongard

[image]
As with my previous puzzle I made the 12 "rooms" larger but kept the same rules. I'm also adding the link to the rules for those that don't know the puzzles [Click me!](http://www.foundalis.com/res/diss_research.html)

And have fun!

Hint:

> the black circles are only cosmetic, please ignore them.

Edit:

> There was a minor mistake that made the puzzle a bit inelegant (the solution was not changed). Now it is fixed, I also removed the incorrect solution that was found; this is the last edit, I will eventually add the answer if no one can find it.

Hint 2:

> Some numbers don't play well with others.

Comment: This one is really frustrating me. Twice I think I've got it and then found one card that doesn't meet the rule...

Comment: @IanF1 Take it easy, this one's a jerk

Comment: The key has got to be the difference between the bottom left of each set

Comment: Could we get a hint for this?  It's been over a year with no one making progress.

Answer (score 16):

Perhaps,

> [image: dsq]
>  The count of intersections between red and black lines is even at left and odd at right.
>  We have 0;2;2;0;2;12 at left and 1;3;1;1;3;1 at right.
>  I'm really not sure about it because of the 5th left picture...

Comment: Nice thinking, but not the answer. Also, due to the ambiguity of the "balls" it's hard to connect them in a definite way. +1 anyway

Comment: @SilverCookies What do you mean by "ambiguity?"

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work

> At most $2$ shoelaces may intersect and non-intersecting shoelaces may not have the highest and lowest endpoints or the rightmost and leftmost endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer could be that

> The line segment on the left only intersect with 1 line segment (either itself or another). Some of the line segment on the right intersect with more than 1 segment.

Comment: Not the answer. Also, not allowed under the rules: the pattern on the right cannot appear in the left boxes, not even once