# Bongardium Leviosa

Tags: pattern, lateral-thinking, science, bongard

This was insprired by [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64862/bongard-number-2-is-here).

This follows the rules of a classic Bongard puzzle: find the rule that all shapes on the left follow, but none of the shapes on the right do.

[image]

To make my intention clearer, here are more examples:

[image]

Assume that the third example on the left is perfectly circular outside of the two missing wedges.

Comment: This may be of help: bayl fgenvtug yvarf ner pbapnir, nyy fzbbgu pheirf ner pbairk.

Comment: To clarify, the fourth shape on the right was changed to make it more clearly not fit the rule.

Comment: I'm unsure about the lower left: For all others: zvffvat funcrf gb na fznyyrfg rapbzcnffvat pvepyr vf rknpgyl gjb

Answer (score 6):

> All the shapes on the left have two or less outward facing corners, but every shape on the right has more than two outward facing corners.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE. To avoid spoiling the puzzle for other users, please use >! to hide your answer from accidental view.

Comment: Good answer! This isn't what I had in mind, but it fits the shapes I included.

Answer (score 2):

This is a little tenuous, but here goes...

> Imagine each shape edge is a string, and each vertex is a hole. Then **attempt to pull each string taut.** Straight edges will remain the same, but curved edges will shrink until they become straight.
>
>
>  Then, the shapes on the left will no longer be closed shapes (either becoming points or lines). The shapes on the right remain as closed shapes.
>
>
>  The contentious one is the pac-man shape (left panel #2/top-right). Perhaps when pulled taut, the string follows the contour of the two existing straight lines, therefore producing a caret (not a closed shape) instead of a triangle (if you were to simply connect the vertices by straight lines). The top-left shape is also contentious; if the three vertices are not collinear, you get a closed triangle upon pulling the strings taut.

Comment: This is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps,

> All the left ones have only axis of symmetry, whereas on the right they have more than one axis of symmetry.

Comment: The centre-right shape on the right has none.

Comment: And the bottom-left and bottom-right shapes on the left have two.

Comment: As Gareth showed, this is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

My thoughts:

> All shapes on the right were modified from an ellipsoid, which were pinched, fused or cut. The ones on the left evolve from a variety of shapes

Comment: This doesn't seem well-defined, and is not what I had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

> Every shape on the left can be stretched into a circle, but those on the right cannot.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE!  Could you explain a bit more how your answer works - especially how it works for the second set of examples?

Answer (score -1):

> All of the shapes on the Left have a vertical line to their right, while none of the shapes on the Right do.

A stretch until I can think of another answer.

Comment: The vertical line should be a separator, and not part of the puzzle; in the original version all 12 shapes are supposed to be boxed